# How to know list of Mondays dates in a month using NSCalendar?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know the dates of all Monday's in a month using NSCalendar in Objective-C. So Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1700102?start=0&tstart=0 and the Apple NSCalendar reference:

How about using something like this -

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:1965]; // Year of the calendar month
[comps setMonth:1]; // Month
[comps setDay:6]; // Any day
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
```

Then, once you have the NSDate, do this:

```
NSDate * testDate = [NSDate date];
NSString * weekdayString = [testDate descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%A" timeZone:nil
 locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]];
NSLog(@"Day of the week: %@", weekdayString);

// weekdayString should look like "Monday", etc.
```

So, you can loop through the month's days until;

```
[weekdayString isEqualToString:@"Monday"] // or your desired day
```

And then just add 7 days to get the other 4 or so dates.

This may not be the prettiest solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I blogged a solution for this a few months ago

http://brandontreb.com/case-of-the-mondays/